# VBA - Filter Friday to Sunday rnage when TODAY is MONDAY, else Filter by Yesterday

Tags: vba, date, filter, moment-business-days

I've been struggling to find a way to filter the date within a range of previous friday to sunday whenever today is MONDAY, so the macro can properly work by itself everyday. If today is not MONDAY, then it should only filter by YESTERDAY

I tried running this code but it gives the me error "Sub or Function not Defined".
also, at the If/Else statement,I lack the knowledge to properly set a date range from friday to sunday.

```
Sub test()


Dim xDay As String
Dim xDate As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
Columns("D:D").Insert
Columns("D:D").Insert
Range("C2").Select
Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select

' Filter & remove TEXT date

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 4), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Columns("D:E").Delete
        
Columns("C:C").Select

Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.NumberFormat = "dddd"
Set xToday = Thisworksheet.Application.Selection.AutoFilter(field(1), Criteria1(Today)) 'this line gives the error "Sub or Function not defined"


If xToday = "Monday" Then
    xDate = Date - 3
Else
    xDate = Date - 1
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Thisworksheet`?

Comment: Oh, looks like I forgot to define it. The file name is RNC_Update

Comment: Also `Today` is not defined. Use `Date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs this in the upcoming future, I'll leave the solution I figured by myself here, after a long bit of research. Of course other people may find some variations to make it easier, but this is working perfectly fine to me.

```
 Sub test()
    
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    StartDate = Date - 3
    EndDate = Date - 1
    Set ws = Worksheets("RNC_Update")
    
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
            
    Columns("C:C").Select
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dddd" 'this will make dates turn into weekdays
    
        With ws
            With Selection
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
            End With
        End With
    
    ' Creating condition: if TODAY is MONDAY, then it will filter records 
' from friday to sunday. If today is not MONDAY, 
' then it will filter by YESTERDAY records
    
    If xlFilterToday = Monday Then
    With Selection
                .NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyy"
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)
                Selection.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyy"
    End With
    Else
        With ws
            With Selection
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterYesterday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
                Selection.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyy"
            End With
        End With
    End If
    
    
    End Sub
```